# Missing scrollbar with jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I already posted a question focused on this problem, but nobody answered. So this is actually a re-post to get the attention back.

My old post can be found here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085891/div-jspverticalbar-missing-inside-the-jspcontainer)

My JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.con').load('views/startseite.html',function(){
        $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
        });
    $('nav a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var inc = $(this).attr('href').split('/').pop().split(".").shift(),
        href = "views/" + inc + ".html"
        $('.con').hide().load(href, function(){
            $('.con').fadeIn('fast',function(){$('.scroll').jScrollPane();});
        })
        document.title =  'Robert-Richter.com | ' + firstToUpperCase(inc)
        location.hash = inc
        return false;
        });
    function firstToUpperCase( str ) {
        return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
    }
});
```

My CSS of the scrollbox:

```
.scroll {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    width: 415px;
    height: 422px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Live exampe of the page with my current code: [Link](http://robert-richter.com/boilerplate4/)

I dont know why some guys always want to read a question, but here we go: Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I think you are missing something in your question writing. The one from yesterday told what was wrong with the page but had no code to speak of. You have lots of downvotes on other questions. Though this one has more code but doesn't say what is wrong. The whole thing needs to be within the one question. People will only invest a little of their time and it has to be easy to help you. Somewhere here are some suggestions for writing better questions you might want to read.

Comment: Im using a lib for a scrollbar, the scrollbar ist not displayed, the title of the question is Missing scrollbar with jScrollPane. What else do you wanna know about it? I placed all required codes in this question. WTF

Comment: Ok. You asked. The problem should be explained in more detail in the body of the question. People read the title. Click to the question and then ignore the title. Then ... What lib? Where is the HTML showing the `<div>` or whatever? What does the 'click' code have to do with a missing scrollbar? Or a function about upper case? None of this is explained. You can edit your question to add all this. Make it as short as you can but easy to read, well organized and complete. Its hard to write a good question.

Comment: Oh. And "Can you help me?" can be safely assumed. The "question" people ask for needs to be very specific.

Comment: If you cant understand what I mean by the information I gave you, your not able to help me.

Comment: True. But everyone one who can't understant what you give us is one less person that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes jquery causes the problem. Please make sure you're not using the 1.8 version (1.7 for example works fine for me). I don't know the exact problem of drupal with jquery 1.8 or higher but it's difficult to find the defect since the browser and drupal log messages aren't showing some error logs. I think it's because jquery is existing but drupal isn't  able to handle it the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Just replied to your old question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440317/1005460 
Let me know in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use autoReinitialise parameter:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
   showArrows: false,
   autoReinitialise: true
});
```

Then I had 1 more problem - I used max-height in my scroll container - this was causing issues as each reinitialisation was setting height one more time, eventualy I just set up fixed height.